# Create input radio through pseudo element :before

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm making a list of items using a simple `ul` structure, and I wanted to put radio inputs at the left of each item.

Pretty simple, but I've got an idea to see if it was possible to generate these radios as pseudo elements, using `:before`.

For test purposes, I tried adding a `appearance: radio;` property to the element, and it worked, but only visually. It is not clickable, and I can't figure out why...

So my question is if it is possible to create a pseudo functional input element? What can I do to make it clickable?

```css
div:before {
    appearance:radio;
    -moz-appearance:radio;
    -webkit-appearance:radio;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: so this is just a test and actually nothing stops you from using `<input type="radio" />` instead...?

Comment: Yes @webeno ... The project is done with the normal way.. Now I'm just curious as if it is possible or not... It might be very useful!

Comment: i'm curious of a use case where adding input wouldn't be possible...

Comment: It doesn't work because it only changes the appearance of an element. It's no actual radiobutton. If you would manage to solve this, there are probably a couple of other issues before you could actually use them. Creating actual inputs would be better, and if you do it server side, it will also work for users that don't have Javascript enabled, and it's more likely to work with screen readers and other aides.